# Reusing my OpenCV C++ files in Android project

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I want to reuse my OpenCV C++ code. I know that I can do so, but I would like to know : do I need to rewrite my functions in a JNI style ? For example do I need to offset my parameters by 2 because the two first parameters passed to my functions will be a JNIenv and a jobject ? This is my first time with JNI, I hope my question is clear.

I'd also like to know, do I need the OpenCV Manager ?

Thanks.

Comment: [RTFM?](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html)